# plotbands on highchart type bar chart endOnTick is not working and want to dynamic the height of the plot bands based on number of seris added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

[image: here in the image plotbands y axis endOnTick is not working for me and also need to reduce the height of the plotbands]

here in the image plotbands y axis endOnTick is not working for me and also need to reduce the height of the plotbands
and here i need dynamic plotband height based on series added
Can anyne please help me here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: i have tried endontick option and tickness for the plotbands height but no luck

Comment: Please reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shirisha_gunda/05pz784j/2/     Here i have added the code need dynamic plotbands height based on series added

Comment: @shirisha thank you for reproducing your code. The `thickness` option works only for the `gauge` series type. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands.thickness Could you explain more precisely what do you have in mind by saying "i have added the code need dynamic plotbands height based on series added"? Do you have an image of the output which you want to achieve?